# Is there a multiprocessing module for Perl?

Tags: multithreading, perl, multiprocessing

Is there a multiprocessing module for Perl? Something that has similar functionality to what's offered by Python's [multiprocessing module](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html).

I understand I could build similar functionality using Perl, but I'm looking for something already implemented.

Comment: Don't forget that Perl has `fork` and `exec` right out of the box.

Comment: Yeah that's the one I added it to the question as well.

Comment: @PlatinumAzure The tricky part is *"The multiprocessing package offers both local and remote concurrency,"* I don't know if there is a portable abstraction for the **remote** part.

Comment: If I needed remote concurrency, I'd start looking at something like gearman and Gearman::XS. If local, then fork/exec or maybe Parallel::ForkManager to manage the processes.

Comment: In addition to fork() there are threads (assuming that your Perl has been compiled for that support).  See 'perlthrtut' [DOC](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlthrtut.html)

Comment: CPAN also offers [Parallel::Pvm - Perl extension for the Parallel Virtual Machine (PVM) Message Passing System](http://search.cpan.org/~dleconte/Parallel-Pvm-1.4.0/Pvm.pm). I have no experience with it. It seems to have the remote process management you're looking for.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think [`Forks::Super`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Forks%3a%3aSuper) comes pretty close. It has a few features for running an arbitrary subroutine (or external command) in a background process, monitoring and signalling the background process, and making interprocess communication a little less painful.

```
use Forks::Super;

sub do_something { my @args = @_; ... }
$process = fork { sub => \&do_something, args => [@args] };
$process->wait;


my $x = 42;
my @y = ();
my %z = ();
sub do_something_else {
    $x = 19;
    @y = qw(foo bar);
    %z = (foo => 'bar');
}
$process = fork { sub => 'do_something_else', share => [\$x, \@y, \%z ] };
$process->wait;
# $x, @y, and %z are now updated with changes made in background process


# create your own pipes to use for IPC
use IO::Handle;
pipe my $child_read, my $parent_write;
pipe my $parent_read, my $child_write;
$parent_write->autoflush(1);
$child_write->autoflush(1);
sub square {
    while (my $x = <$child_read>) {
        print {$child_write} $x ** 2, "\n";
    }
    close $child_write;
}
$process = fork { sub => 'square' };
print {$parent_write} "9\n";
my $result = <$parent_read>;    # should be "81\n";
close $parent_write;

# or use the standard I/O handles for IPC
sub square_root {
    sleep 1 && seek STDIN,0,1 while eof(STDIN); # ok, this is a workaround for an existing bug :-(
    while (my $x = <STDIN>) {
        print sqrt($x), "\n";
    }
}
$process = fork { sub => 'square_root', child_fh => 'in,out,block' };
$process->write_stdin("81\n");
$result = $process->read_stdout(); #  =>  "9\n"
```

Both the `multiprocessing` module and `Forks::Super` have a lot of features. Which ones are you specifically interested in?

I am the author of `Forks::Super` and my goal is to include any features for parallel processing that people find useful, so if there's a feature in `multiprocessing` that you want in Perl, let me know.

Comment: This is just what I was looking for. I got this task to add parallelism to improve running times on some Perl scripts we have. I had used Python's multiprocessing before, but nothing like that in Perl. I'll have more specific questions as I start to convert the scripts.

Comment: Ugh, I just checked if this module is installed in my Perl, and apparently it's not. I wish essential stuff like this was part of the standard Perl package. :(

Comment: I'm using Forks::Super on Windows 10 with Strawberry Perl 5.30, and it seems when I use Forks::Super::fork( 'sub' => \&myFunc ... ); it doesn't actually launch a child process. Is it possible that on Windows, Forks::Super merely emulates the normal Unix fork behavior via threads? :-\

Comment: Yes, to run a Perl subroutine in the background on Windows, `Forks::Super` will use the builtin `fork` call which spawns a *pseudo-process* for the child code to run in.

Comment: @mob And I suppose that means if I used Forks::Super to parallelize a bunch of work to take advantage of the CPU's multiple cores then this emulation behavior kind of defeats that purpose, since this pseudo-process is really just a thread, and Perl's threads do not really run in parallel (due to some global interpreter lock, similar to Python's GIL), if I understand correctly.

Comment: No you do not understand correctly. Windows threads can run in parallel. For that matter, so do Perl threads.

Comment: @mob You're right. I had an error in my code. Now that I have fixed it I'm seeing that using Forks::Super to parallelize tasks really does make use of my system's cores.

Comment: @mob By the way, just to clarify, I was not questioning Windows' ability to run threads in parallel. I just know that in Python, if you launch user threads, they won't really run in parallel because there is a global interpreter lock in Python that prevents them from actually running in parallel. I mistakenly assumed that Perl has the same issue.

Comment: @antred Perl "interpreter-based threads" (`use threads`) have that issue. But those are different, and I believe all such Perl threads run inside a single Windows thread. When using the fork() emulation, you get multiple distinct Windows threads (instead of the processes you get on POSIX systems), which are generally good enough.

Answer (score 12):

[forks](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?forks) provides the same awesome interface as [threads](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?threads), but uses processes instead of threads.

```
use forks;  # Or: use threads;
use Thread::Queue;

my $q = Thread::Queue->new();

my @workers;
for (1..NUM_WORKERS) {
   push @workers, async {
      while (defined(my $job = $q->dequeue())) {
         ...
      }
   };
}

$q->enqueue(...);

$q->enqueue(undef) for @workers;
$_->join for @workers;
```

---

Comparing forks with Forks::Super.

Keep in mind, these are suppose to the be the cases where Forks::Super excels!

```
use Forks::Super;
sub do_something { my @args = @_; ... }
$process = fork { sub => \&do_something, args => [@args] };
$process->wait;
```

can be written as

```
use forks;
sub do_something { my @args = @_; ... }
$process = async { do_something(@args) };
$process->join;
```

---

```
use Forks::Super;
my $x = 42;
my @y = ();
my %z = ();
sub do_something_else {
    $x = 19;
    @y = qw(foo bar);
    %z = (foo => 'bar');
}
$process = fork { sub => 'do_something_else', share => [\$x, \@y, \%z ] };
$process->wait;
```

can be written as

```
use forks;
use forks::shared;
my $x :shared = 42;
my @y :shared = ();
my %z :shared = ();
sub do_something_else {
    $x = 19;
    @y = qw(foo bar);
    %z = (foo => 'bar');
}
$process = async { do_something_else() };
$process->join;
```

---

```
use Forks::Super;
use IO::Handle;
pipe my $child_read, my $parent_write;
pipe my $parent_read, my $child_write;
$parent_write->autoflush(1);
$child_write->autoflush(1);
sub square {
    while (my $x = <$child_read>) {
        chomp($x);
        print {$child_write} $x ** 2, "\n";
    }
    close $child_write;
}
$process = fork { sub => 'square' };
print { $parent_write } "9\n";
chomp( my $result = <$parent_read> );  # 81
close $parent_write;
$process->wait;
```

can be written as

```
use forks;
use Threads::Queue;
my $req = Threads::Queue->new();
my $resp = Threads::Queue->new();
sub square { $_[0] ** 2 }
$process = async {
    while (defined(my $x = $req->dequeue())) {
        $resp->enqueue( square($x) );
    }
};
$req->enqueue(9);
my $result = $resp->dequeue();  # 81
$resp->enqueue(undef);
$process->join;
```

---

```
use Forks::Super;
sub square_root {
    sleep 1 && seek STDIN,0,1 while eof(STDIN); # ok, this is a workaround for an existing bug :-(
    while (my $x = <STDIN>) {
        chomp($x);
        print sqrt($x), "\n";
    }
}
$process = fork { sub => 'square_root', child_fh => 'in,out,block' };
$process->write_stdin("81\n");
chomp( $result = $process->read_stdout() );  # 9
$process->close_fh('stdin');
$process->wait;
```

can be written as

```
use forks;
use Threads::Queue;
my $req = Threads::Queue->new();
my $resp = Threads::Queue->new();
$process = async {
    while (defined(my $x = $req->dequeue())) {
        $resp->enqueue( sqrt($x) );
    }
};
$req->enqueue(81);
my $result = $resp->dequeue();  # 9
$resp->enqueue(undef);
$process->join;
```

Comment: @jkysam, Added comparison of forks and Forks::Super.

Answer (score 3):

What about [POE: Perl Object Environment](http://poe.perl.org)?  It has support for asynchronous child processes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/marioroy/mce-perl
It is similar to python multiprocess module

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)