# Perl threading model

Tags: multithreading, perl

- I have 100+ tasks to do, I can do it in a loop, but that will be slow
- I want to do these jobs by threading, let's say, 10 threads
- There is no dependency between the jobs, each can run independently, and stop if failed
- I want these threads to pick up my jobs and do it, there should be no more than 10 threads in total, otherwise it may harm the server
- These threads keep doing the jobs until all finished
- Stop the job in the thread when timeout

I was searching information about this on the Internet, `Threads::Pool`, `Threads::Queue`...
But I can't be sure on which one is better for my case. Could anyone give me some advise?

Comment: what do the jobs produce as output?  files? in-memory data?  if the latter, how big/how is it structured?  Windows or non-windows?

Comment: the jobs are doing down/ up action on application services, no output need to capture, no file input, what I need to do is to pass the service name into the function, and then let the command to stop/ start it. Sorry, I forgot to mention, it's running on Linux

Comment: then I would just use Parallel::ForkManager.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Thread::Queue and threads.

The IPC (communication between threads) is much easier tan between processes.

[To fork or not to fork?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13162235/to-fork-or-not-to-fork/13163361#13163361)

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use threads;
use Thread::Queue;

my $q = Thread::Queue->new();    # A new empty queue

# Worker thread
my @thrs = threads->create(sub {
                            while (my $item = $q->dequeue()) {
                                # Do work on $item
                            }
                         })->detach() for 1..10;#for 10 threads
my $dbh = ...
while (1){
  #get items from db
  my @items = get_items_from_db($dbh);
  # Send work to the thread
  $q->enqueue(@items);
  print "Pending items: "$q->pending()."\n";
  sleep 15;#check DB in every 15 secs
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will study it in office. Many people asked me to do by fork,what's the adv of fork over thread ? Does it consume more system resources?

Answer (score 0):

I'd never use perl threads.  The reason is that they aren't conceptually speaking threads: you have to specify what data is to be shared between the threads. Each thread runs a perl interpreter.  That's why they are called interpreterthreads or ithreads. Needless to say, this consumes alot of memory all for running things in parallel. fork() shares al the memory up until the fork point. So if they are independent tasks, always use fork. It's also the most Unix way of doing things.