# Perl Multithread Program

Tags: multithreading, perl

I am new in Perl. I want to write a Perl script using thread.I have few files say 20 files and want to process those files using 5 threads in 4 batches. I am printing the thread no. After completing one batch ,the thread no must start with 1 for the next batch. But instead of that its creating 20 threads.please help. my code is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use threads;
use threads::shared;

my $INPUT_DIR="/home/Documents/myscript/IMPORTLDIF/";
opendir(DIR, $INPUT_DIR) ;
my @files = grep { /^InputFile/ } readdir DIR;
my $count = @files;
#print "Total Files: $count \n";
my @threads;
my $noofthread = 5;
my $nooffiles = $count;
my $noofbatch = $nooffiles / $noofthread;
#print "No of batch: $noofbatch \n";

my $fileIndex = 0;
my $batch = 1;
while ($fileIndex < $nooffiles) {
    print "Batch: $batch \n";
    for (my $i=0; $i < $noofthread && $fileIndex < $nooffiles ; $i++) {

        my $t = threads->new(\&doOperation, $files[$fileIndex], $i)->join;
        push(@threads, $t);
        $fileIndex++;
        print "FileIndex: $fileIndex \n";
    }
    $batch++;
}

sub doOperation () {
    my $ithread = threads->tid() ;
    print "Thread Index : [id=$ithread]\n" ;
    foreach my $item (@_){
        my $filename = $item;
        print "Filename name: $filename \n";
    }
```

Edited program using thread queue:

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl -w 
    # This is compiled with threading support

    use strict;
    use warnings;

    use threads;
    use Thread::Queue;

    my $q = Thread::Queue->new(); # A new empty queue

    # Worker thread
    my $INPUT_DIR="/home/Documents/myscript/IMPORTLDIF/";
    opendir(DIR, $INPUT_DIR) or die "Cannot opendir: $!";

    my @thrs = threads->create(\&doOperation ) for 1..5;#for 5 threads
    #my @files = `ls -1 /home/Documents/myscript/IMPORTLDIF/`;
    my @files = grep { /^Input/ } readdir DIR or die "File not present present. \n";
    chomp(@files);

    #add files to queue
    foreach my $f (@files){
    # Send work to the thread
    $q->enqueue($f);
    print "Pending items: " + $q->pending()."\n";
    }

    $q->enqueue('_DONE_') for @thrs;
    $_->join() for @thrs;



    sub doOperation () {
    my $ithread = threads->tid() ;
    while (my $filename = $q->dequeue()) {
     # Do work on $item
    return 1 if $filename eq '_DONE_';
    print "[id=$ithread]\t$filename\n";
   }
    return 1;
    }
```

Comment: Your formatting is broken. Please take a moment to [edit] your question. I cannot fix it for you because I'm not sure what actually belongs to the code and what doesn't. If you are having trouble, there's excellent help in the edit screen for markup syntax.

Comment: Hi I have chnaged the formatting.Is that ok now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are spawning a thread and then waiting for it to complete before spawning the next, each thread handling one file.  That is why you see as many threads as you have files.

```
my $t = threads->new(\&doOperation, $files[$fileIndex], $i)->join;
                                                             ^^^^--- This will block
```

Instead try something like this:

```
....

# split the workload into N batches
#
while (my @batch = splice(@files, 0, $batch_size)) {
  push @threads, threads->new(\&doOperation, @batch);
}

# now wait for all workers to finish
#
for my $thr (@threads) {
  $thr->join;
}
```

As an aside, [Thread::Queue](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Thread-Queue/) and [Thread-Pool](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Thread-Pool/) might imply better designs for the work you want to do.

Comment: I was using the thread queue.But its not working. could you help me?I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Paralel:Queue and create 4 thread and pass them items that they could work on.

[To fork or not to fork?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13162235/to-fork-or-not-to-fork/13163361#13163361)

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use threads;
use Thread::Queue;

my $q = Thread::Queue->new();    # A new empty queue

# Worker thread
my @thrs;
push @thrs, threads->create(\&doOperation ) for 1..5;#for 5 threads
my @files = `ls -1 /tmp/`;chomp(@files);
#add files to queue
foreach my $f (@files){
  # Send work to the thread
  $q->enqueue($f);
  print "Pending items: "$q->pending()."\n";
}
$q->enqueue('_DONE_') for @thrs;
$_->join() for threads->list();



sub doOperation () {
    my $ithread = threads->tid() ;
    while (my $filename = $q->dequeue()) {
      # Do work on $item
      return 1 if $filename eq '_DONE_';
      print "[id=$ithread]\t$filename\n";
    }
    return 1;
}
```