# Perl Multithreading not running batch command

Tags: multithreading, perl, batch-file

I am trying to use `perl` multithreading to run each of the `cmd.exe` commands, contained within a large file similar to this:

```
copy file1.txt file2.txt
copy file3.txt file4.txt
...
copy file5000.txt file5001.txt
```

I looked at the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23470376) and tried a sample test for copying just two files.

The problem is that the command never gets called. It never makes a copy of the files even though they are there and in the same folder where I am running the perl script.

What am I doing wrong?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use threads;
use Thread::Queue; 

print "Perl Starting ... \n\n"; 

my $q = Thread::Queue->new();    # A new empty queue

# Worker thread
my @thrs = threads->create(\&doOperation ) for 1..5;#for 5 threads

my @files = ("copy file123.xml test1.xml", "copy file123.xml test2.xml");
#add files to queue
foreach my $f (@files){
  # Send work to the thread
  $q->enqueue($f);
  print "Pending items: ". $q->pending() ."\n";
}
$q->enqueue('_DONE_') for @thrs;
$_->join() for @thrs;



sub doOperation () {
    my $ithread = threads->tid() ;
    while (my $cmd = $q->dequeue()) {
      # Do work on $item

      print "cmd: $cmd ... \n";
      print "Running Dos command ... \n";

      my $status = system("$cmd");

      print "Status: $status ... \n";
      print "End Dos command ... \n";

      return 1 if $cmd eq '_DONE_';
      print "[id=$ithread]\t$cmd\n";
    }
    return 1;
}


print "\nPerl End ... \n\n";
```

…and here's the output in `cmd.exe`

```
Perl Starting ...

Pending items: 1
cmd: copy file123.xml test1.xml ...
Running Dos command ...
Pending items: 0
cmd: copy file123.xml test2.xml ...

Running Dos command ...
Perl End ...

Perl exited with active threads:
        5 running and unjoined
        0 finished and unjoined
        0 running and detached
```

PS. I already tried Parallel::ForkManager and that keeps crashing on me after X number of processing on my windows server so that's why I am looking for an alternate solution.

Comment: Replace `$_->join() for @thrs;` with `$_->join() for threads->list();`

Comment: Thanks that did do the copy finally but the perl script never ends. It just hangs and I have to do crtl+c on the DOS prompt where I am running it. Can you try that code out. Its a working code

Comment: that's what basically a you are doing in the script by threading you commands (an infinite loop), if you want avoid all the threading issues better to try forking (function simillar to threads but more trustable in perl) using some easy module like `Parallel::ForkManager`, here's the documentation if you like https://metacpan.org/pod/Parallel::ForkManager

Comment: See my comments about ForkManager  in my post.

Comment: @Mobrine Hayde, `fork` is (poorly) emulated using threads on Windows. That makes P::FM the more complicated option there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following declaration results in @thrs having zero elements.

```
my @thrs = threads->create(\&doOperation ) for 1..5;#for 5 threads
```

You are then referring to @thrs in two places. If you replace all of those references with `threads->list()` as Mobrine indicates (not just one reference but two), then you will make progress.

Or you can fix the declaration like this:

```
my @thrs;
push @thrs, threads->create(\&doOperation ) for 1..5;
```

Regarding your comment on your question about fixing one reference allowing the copies to take place but not your script's termination: you probably didn't fix the second reference, the one that enqueues the DONE, preventing each thread from breaking its while loop.

---

In his comment below and assuming you need to keep your own list of threads, ikegami shows the more perly way to create the list:

```
my @thrs = map { threads->create(\&doOperation ) } 1..5;
```

Comment: Or `my @thrs = map { threads->create(\&doOperation ) } 1..5;`

Comment: Or just `threads->create(\&doOperation ) for 1..5;` with `$_->join for threads->list;`