# Splitting array for multiple threads

Tags: arrays, perl, for-loop

I have a script where i load in a large array with over 3 million values at a time.

I can easily run through the list with "for", it works nice, and clean. But to speed up my script i would like to know if it would be possible to split the main array into X number of other arrays automatically and run each in a for loop (maybe each in a separate thread).

I would like the arrays to be flexible, so i could choose lets say 4 and it would split it into 4 arrays.

Comment: The obvious way is to share the big array across the threads, but if that array has been populated by just reading data from a file then you may as well get each thread to read its own chunk for itself. What is the result of processing this array? Is it another equally large array, or is just something like `42`?

Comment: Basically, its a whole /8 block of ip address's so 16777214 items in the array.. which is a lot ;-;, when i tried using threads or forking with it. it seemed that just using "for" instaid of forks or threads worked a lot faster and a lot lower server resources.

Comment: Okay so it's a calculated set of 2²⁴  values. What are you doing with them in the `for` loop? It may be best to show your threaded code and ask why it's not performing better, but remember that threads are only faster if there are parts of the process that can be done in parallel - most commonly one thread would be calculating while another is writing to disk. If there is only CPU-intensive work to be done and your `for` loop is pushing the processor as fast as it will go then the only difference threads will make is to add an overhead to split the job up.

Comment: Well, when using threads it used 27% of three cores and it got 10Gigs of ram, with just one for loop it used 3% of one core, and 358mb ram.

Comment: Ouch. And yet the threaded version was slower? Sounds like a bad trade off to me! I've no idea whether Perl threads are any good at sharing the work across processors. You need to show your code.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Paralel::Queue and threads. You could use another mmodules or fork as well but it is much easier to share data in threads than in between processes.

I think your problem was with your threaded code that you have created the arrays then the threads. This way every thread copied your array. It is much more efficient to use queues to send data to threads.

See some examples here for other methods: [To fork or not to fork?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13162235/to-fork-or-not-to-fork/13163361#13163361)

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use threads;
use Thread::Queue;

my $q = Thread::Queue->new();    # A new empty queue
my $num_of_threads=4;
# Worker thread creation
my @thrs = threads->create(sub {
                            while (my $item = $q->dequeue()) {
                                return 1 if $item eq 'STOP_TH';
                                process_item($item);
                            }
                         }) for 1..$num_of_threads;

### you are reading your data in loop
while (..){
  ### put data into threads queue
  $q->enqueue(@items);
}
### signal the threads that you have no more data
$q->enqueue('STOP_TH') for 1..$num_of_threads;
### wait until all threads finish
$_->join() for @thrs;

sub process_item {
  my $item = shift;
  ### do whatever you like with item

}
```